# find_by_sql fails with exception: wrong number of parameters

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the following code find_by_sql fails with exception:  wrong number of parameters (0 for 1). 
Any idea what's going on?

```
def filter_new_unfollowers(unfollower_ids)
  relationships = TwitterRelationship.find_by_sql["SELECT * FROM  twitter_relationships
                           INNER JOIN twitter_identities ON (twitter_identities.twitter_id=twitter_relationships.source_twitter_id)
                           INNER JOIN member_twitter_identities ON (member_twitter_identities.twitter_identity_id = twitter_identities.id) 
                            WHERE member_twitter_identities.member_id IN (?)", unfollower_ids]

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding brackets:

```
relationships = TwitterRelationship.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM  twitter_relationships
                           INNER JOIN twitter_identities ON (twitter_identities.twitter_id=twitter_relationships.source_twitter_id)
                           INNER JOIN member_twitter_identities ON (member_twitter_identities.twitter_identity_id = twitter_identities.id)
                            WHERE member_twitter_identities.member_id IN (?)", unfollower_ids])
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you wrote it, you are trying to execute find_by_sql with no arguments, and then call the [] operator on the result (but it failed before you got that far).

You need a space before the "[".  To be even more clear, I would put parentheses around the array argument "...find_by_sql([...])".